# Run SvelteKit app on production as server

Tags: build, svelte, sveltekit

I have an app created with last SveltieKit, how can I run results of `npm run build` as server?

After build I have created `.sveltie-kit` folder with multiple files inside. I tried to run `node .sveltie-kit/build/server.js` but it does not work.

Versions:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.1",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.2",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "svelte": "^3.55.0",
    "svelte-check": "^3.0.1",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^5.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "vite": "^4.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: What server do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want SvelteKit to generate a standalone Node server you have to use the [node adapter](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node).

```js
// svelte.config.js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

export default {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter()
  }
};
```

By default this will create a `build` directory you can run `node` on.

```bash
node build
```

Comment: Just to clarify, as this confused me for first: `node build` will automatically run `node build/index.js`.

Comment: Also to further clarify, this is a wrapper script for [Polka web server](https://github.com/lukeed/polka).